Searching for a specific sci-fi movie, vague informations
I'm currently searching for a sci-fi movie, which i saw a trailer of on TV some years ago.  If my remembrance is right, it was an alien invasion movie.
What i remember:

A woman on a screen saying something like: ''dont do anything against us'' blabla.
Skyscrapers with a BIG and VERY SILVERY SHINING space ship hovering over them,  the space ship also has a big screen on the bottom of it,
showing this woman talking to the earths population.


This sounds like the TV series V (2009):
     [Source]

A remake of the 1983 miniseries. 
The new series chronicles the arrival on Earth of a technologically advanced alien species which ostensibly comes in peace, but actually has sinister motives.


ah you little weasle... was totally gonna post that, too ;) seems like a perfect match

I was going to post that one too!  Although it would be funny if all three of us were wrong
